# Rattlesnakes developing stronger venom

Tags: reptile

I have heard that rattlesnakes are developing stronger venoms causing more people each year to die from rattlesnake bites.

But why would a snake that is already very venomous need to develop stronger venoms? I mean for the venom resistant ground squirrels couldn't the snake just wait longer or maybe strike more than once before it eats?

And I could see this going to venom overload in the next few centuries. If rattlesnakes keep developing stronger venoms at the pace that they are then rattlesnakes could become as venomous as a cobra or worse. Along with that it might rattle less and less until it just stops using the rattle.

Is is because of the fact that we are developing stronger pit viper antivenoms(mainly by injecting rattlesnake venom, copperhead venom, and cottonmouth venom into an animal with a stronger immune system like a horse and after a while, getting the antibodies needed for the antivenom) that rattlesnakes are developing stronger venoms?

Comment: Can you add the source which says that the venom is getting stronger?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRf4u8qE4Vs This video mentions rattlesnake venom getting stronger and ground squirrels becoming more resistant to rattlesnake venom.

Comment: @Caters Youtube is not generally considered a valid source of reference. There must be some kind of report that says so, unless they wouldn't have made the documentary. Even though the documentary is from a credible source, the first exercise should be to verify it. Because the rest of the question is based on the assumption that the initial statement is correct. Also, one cannot watch the entire documentary for a specific fact.

Comment: Also have a look at [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0041010110000991)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find an article which mentions the venom strengthening: 
http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/06/120605102638.htm

It may be an evolutionary bonus. Snakes with the most potent venom may leave fewer survivors, particularly with something like humans who would hunt down a snake if they could find it. A snake which leaves fewer survivors may be better able to escape. It may also have more successful hunts which may have been what lead them to become poisonous to begin with.

Unlike the antibiotics arms race against bacteria, it's unlikely that antivenoms are the cause of more dangerous snakes.

As far as "centuries from now" we really can't hypothesize whether more potent venom will continue to be a more helpful evolutionary trait. More potent venom doesn't have an infinitely continuing effectiveness. After a certain point, whatever bitten isn't any more dead with a stronger poison.

Comment: Please vote for my answer and marked it as "answer" (the check mark) if you found it at all helpful. Your questions are conjecture and you are not understanding how ecological systems work. The changes in venom are small and not infinite. Other systems tend to balance changes appropriately. The only big changes happening more rapidly than nature is able to cope with are those made by man. It is highly unlikely that a small increase in poison effectiveness will throw the entire system off course.